# 'Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am using textbox as search for number, when I put number it searched but when I erased it from box I got error.

my code is:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     TextBox2.TextChanged
   SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = "SerialNumber = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'"
End Sub
```

the error is:

> Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.

Comment: When you use numbers in VB, do you put double-quotes around them?  No, you don't.  Double quotes are only for text.  The same goes in SQL code (the `Filter` property contains a SQL `WHERE` clause) except that you use single-quotes for text.  You still don't use any quotes for numbers though.  If the `SerialNumber` column contains `Integer` values then you have to compare it to `Integer` values, not `Strings`.

Comment: As it happens, your code is wrong but would still work if the value you provided actually was a number.  If you get that exception then `TextBox2` doesn't contain a numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that empty string validation failed.

For empty string you should remove the filter.

#### It should be something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     TextBox2.TextChanged
   if Trim(TextBox2.Text) = "" Then
     SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = ""
   Else
     SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = "SerialNumber = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'"
   End If
End Sub
```

## EDIT

You can also check each inserted data with `KeyUp` event:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyUp
    If NumericMode Then ' NumericMode is boolean and should be turnd On/Off elswhere
        If  Char.IsDigit(ChrW(e.KeyValue)) Then
           'OK
        Else
           'ERROR 
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: could you guide me how to verify the input to be an integer? the data in SerialNumber are numbers not text!

Comment: That will still fail if the `TextBox` contains text that is not numeric.  The data should be validated using `Integer.TryParse`, either here or, even better, in the `Validating` event handler of the `TextBox`.  Also, those single-quotes still shouldn't be there.  You don't quote numbers.

Comment: Better use `NumericUpDown` instead of `TextBox` to get only numbers.

Comment: #SHR Thanks for your solution it works! but what if want to search by name in the same textbox?

Comment: @MohammadKhaled, if you want to do something other than what this question specifies then you should post another question about that new topic.  Of course, as always, you need to make your own attempt first and then show us that if and when it doesn't work.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes thank you I put it in another post.

Comment: @SHR I tried this : 
[Private Sub TextBox3_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyUp
        If TextBox3.Text Then ' NumericMode is boolean and should be turnd On/Off elswhere
            If Char.IsDigit(ChrW(e.KeyValue)) Then
                SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = "SerialNumber = '" + TextBox3.Text + "'"
            Else
                SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = "Fullname LIKE '" + TextBox3.Text + "%'"
        End If
    End Sub]

search with number is OK but when go to search by letters it gave me error

Answer (score 1):

```
    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    'This would work, but would consider decimals also a number
    If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then
        SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("SerialNumber = '{0}'", TextBox2.Text)
        Return
    End If
    SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = ""
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    'This would work if you want to guarantee an Int32
    Dim txtInt As Integer
    If Int32.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, TxtInt) Then
        SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("SerialNumber = '{0}'", txtInt)
    Else
        SpringDataBindingSource.Filter = ""
    End If

End Sub
```